# Building chat bot with aiml vs nodejs

Tags: node.js, chatbot, aiml, botframework

I have a requirement to service my website customers with queries regarding courses offered, its fees, course details and timings, etc.

With `aiml`, I can put it my business logic straightup without any AI OR ML where as with Microsoft Bot Framework (`Node.js` version), I see that I will have to write lot of waterfall approach style of coding chaining up functions to complete the customer queries.

Then my question is how does it become intelligent or machine learning if I manually write chained functions? and where do I put in my series of question and answers if I choose to use Microsoft Bot Framework?

I am confused looking at different approaches. Which approach would be suitable for my requirement?